# Building Mono Without Bash: Syntax Error in doltlibtool

Tags: bash, shell, build, mono

I'm building mono on an android device and getting an error when the build runs ./doltlibtool

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/bld/mono/mono-4.0.0/eglib/src'
  CC       libeglib_la-garray.lo
../doltlibtool: line 4: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

Here is line 4 of doltlibtool:

```
1 #!/bin/bash                                                                          
2 top_builddir_slash="${0%%doltlibtool}"
3 : ${top_builddir_slash:=./}
4 args=()
5 modeok=false                                                                         
6 tagok=false
```

From what I can tell, the problem is due to the fact that I'm not using bash.  Is there any way to fix this without building and using bash?

**CORRECTION**
I am using bash...but the busybox version of bash, which isn't really bash and so does not support arrays.

Comment: Remove line numbers.

Comment: line numbers aren't in the original file...I only added them for clarification

Comment: Search for special characters with GNU cat: `cat -v doltlibtool`.

Comment: Don't see any in the output. Is there a utility for removing them if they are there?

Comment: Could whomever down-voted the original question add some reason/explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the mono-devel mailing list, to which I posted the question:
**Is it possible to build mono without bash?**

> It is unlikely.
>   Your best bet is to cross compile.

Shells that do not handle arrays (like the default Android shell or the default shell in KBOX...which is a busybox version of bash) cannot be used when compiling mono 4.0.0. Specifically the line

```
args=()
```

will throw an error.

I ended up downloading the bash source and building it before trying to build mono